# Why Nginx implement ip_hash load balancing method with these 3 primes

Tags: nginx, primes

I notice that Nginx selected 3 primes, 89, 113 and 6271, to implement the ip_hash load balancing method, why these 3 primes?

Is it more fair than just `% number of servers`?

```
$ factor 89 113 6271
89: 89
113: 113
6271: 6271

// https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/4bf4650f2f10f7bbacfe7a33da744f18951d416d/src/http/modules/ngx_http_upstream_ip_hash_module.c

static ngx_int_t
ngx_http_upstream_init_ip_hash_peer(ngx_http_request_t *r,
                                    ngx_http_upstream_srv_conf_t *us)
{
    // ...
    ngx_http_upstream_ip_hash_peer_data_t  *iphp;

    iphp = ngx_palloc(r->pool, sizeof(ngx_http_upstream_ip_hash_peer_data_t));

   // ...
   iphp->hash = 89;
   // ...
}

static ngx_int_t
ngx_http_upstream_get_ip_hash_peer(ngx_peer_connection_t *pc, void *data)
{
    // ...
    for ( ;; ) {
        for (i = 0; i < (ngx_uint_t) iphp->addrlen; i++) {
            hash = (hash * 113 + iphp->addr[i]) % 6271;
        }
    // ...
    }
    // ...

    iphp->hash = hash;
}
```

As the document said, "The first three octets of the client IPv4 address, or the entire IPv6 address, are used as a hashing key.", So let there be a IPv4 address, `iphp->addrlen = 3`, and `iphp->addr[0]` is the first octet of the IPv4 address, `iphp->addr[1]` is the second one, ...